# org.apache.curator.ConnectionState Connection timed out for connection string

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

I have been facing this issue for my Solr instance which is managed by Zookeeper.

It appears that Zookeeper is able to send requests to Zookeeper which momentarily accepts the request and then refuses it.

In Zookeeper logs, I have been seeing this error:

```
INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.Client.environment:user.dir=/ [1635628661@qtp-2049348234-50]
INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=150000 watcher=org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@c4f2fbd [1635628661@qtp-2049348234-50]
INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) [1635628661@qtp-2049348234-50-SendThread(localhost:2181)]
INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session [1635628661@qtp-2049348234-50 SendThread(localhost:2181)]
ERROR org.apache.curator.ConnectionState  Connection timed out for connection string (localhost:2181) and timeout (15000) / elapsed (15290) [1635628661@qtp-204934823450]
org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.checkTimeouts(ConnectionState.java:191)
at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:86)
at org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:113)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl getZooKeeper(CuratorF
```

Any help is appreciated here.

Comment: Did you get solution on this

Answer (score 0):

According to log you have opened socket on localhost:2181, so line:

```
INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session [1635628661@qtp-2049348234-50 SendThread(localhost:2181)]
```

Is states like, ok, we found an opened socket, now we attempt to write some data. And it sends connection request sending sessionId and password. If session is not already established - it is sends 0 as session id, but sends *password*.

If you will enable debug output you would see in log then something like

```
Session establishment request sent on <remote address>
```

Log record you asking about -

```
ERROR org.apache.curator.ConnectionState  Connection timed out for connection string (localhost:2181) and timeout (15000) / elapsed (15290) [1635628661@qtp-204934823450]
```

related to curator itself. If client not connected - it call checkTimeout() and if check timeout result is 'CONNECTION_TIMEOUT' generates record like above.

Not so much information but I try to guess there is zookeper on your localhost but connection rejected, may be password required or something else.

Hope it will help.

(my answer is based on curator code from master here -> https://github.com/apache/curator)